# Advice for Kalman filter for position with velocity input

Tags: kalman-filters

I am currently building a Kalman filter to add positions derived from high-sample rate velocity data (from an IMU) to lower-sample rate GNSS data. Normally, I understand you would use acceleration data, however this is the only data I have available. I am looking for advice on whether I have built my Kalman filter correctly.

Since position estimates are derived from the given velocities, I have set the state variables to the X, Y, and Z positions. I was unsure if I should include velocity as a state variable as well, but this seemingly breaks the filter.

The velocity data are sampled at 20 Hz and the GNSS data are sampled at 1 Hz, so I call for an update to the position once every 20 cycles. Unfortunately, the beautifully smooth positions derived from the velocities are "dragged" sharply toward the GNSS locations. I am at a loss for what to do in order to smooth the solution.

In the attached image I show the results of the forward, reversed, and combined Kalman filter solutions, as well as the original GNSS track.

I have also included my code:

```
class GNSS_filter:

def __init__(self, row):
    dt = 5e-2

    self.Nx = 3 # number of states: pos
    self.Nu = 3 # number of input var: vel

    self.X = np.zeros([self.Nx, 1]) # error states: pos_ned

    # Initial antenna location
    pos_ned = row[['pos_n','pos_e','pos_d']].values.reshape(3,1)
    self.X[0:3] = pos_ned

# Process model

    # State transition matrix
    self.F = np.identity(self.Nx)

    self.P = np.identity(self.Nx)

    # Process noise matrix
    self.gnss_pos_psd = 0.004

    self.Q = np.zeros([self.Nx, self.Nx])

    self.updateQ(dt)

    # Position measurement noise
    self.R_position = np.identity(3)*0.02

def updateQ(self,dt):
    # Position estimation noise
    self.Q[0:3, 0:3] = np.identity(3)*self.gnss_pos_psd*dt

def predict(self, v_ned, dt):

    u = np.zeros([self.Nx, 1])
    u[0:3] = v_ned * dt  # Displacement
    
    self.updateQ(dt)

    self.X = self.X + u
    self.P = self.F@self.P@self.F.transpose() + self.Q

def updatePosition(self, pos_ned= np.zeros([1,3])):
    H = np.zeros([3, self.Nx])
    H[0:3, 0:3] = np.identity(3)

    y = pos_ned - H @ self.X
    S = H @ self.P @ H.transpose() + self.R_position
    K = (self.P @ H.transpose()) @ inv(S)
    self.X = self.X + K @ y

    I = np.identity(self.Nx)
    self.P = (I - K @ H) @ self.P

def get_states(self):
    return {
            "pos_n": np.ndarray.item(self.X[0]),
            "pos_e": np.ndarray.item(self.X[1]),
            "pos_d": np.ndarray.item(self.X[2]),
    }
```

[image]

Comment: An IMU, by itself, cannot give you velocity data -- the only thing that an IMU measures is acceleration and rotational velocity.  You've got something calling itself an IMU that's delivering impossible data -- which means it's a "smart" IMU doing goodness-knows-what under the hood.  You need to find out what that goodness-knows-what actually is before you can do anything sensible with it.

Comment: Yes, I know that the unit is doing some calculations under-the-hood. Here is specific information on the file I have information from: https://docs.novatel.com/OEM7/Content/SPAN_Logs/INSPVA.htm

Edit: Copied the wrong link

Comment: That appears to be the data for your receiver, not your IMU -- or the receiver includes an IMU and does its own calculations, or something.  Why don't you _edit your question_ -- put in that link, make sure you point out that it's the receiver, and then also link to the data for the IMU.